# Example of WebRTC Peer Connection Involving Different Html Pages?

Tags: webrtc

All the examples in the RTCPeerConnection section of webrtc.github.io/samples/ work off of a **single** html page.  In Does anyone know of a WebRTC example involving **2 or more** html pages?

Answer (score 0):

Her is an example implementation with simple-peer https://github.com/Dirvann/webrtc-video-conference-simple-peer

Comment: In this example, one peer is an html page and the other seems to be a server running nodejs.  I'm looking for an example in which each peer is an html page.